# ASP.NET Core, AddOpenIdConnect - does ValidateIssuerSigningKey need to have a IssuerSigningKey?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have a working open id authentication in my ASP.NET Core application. Now I asked myself, if the issuer token is automatically validated. I wasn't sure, so I did this

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MetadataAddress");
    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority");
    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
```

Now i was wondering, if I set ValidateIssuerSigningKey to true, do I have to set a IssuerSigningKey? I didn't get any info in the documentations.

The issue I see is, that the signing algorithm can be whatever is possible. The MetadataAddress will tell it to me in the id_token_signing_alg_values_supported property, but do I have to implement any possible algorithm? Or does Microsofts IdentityModel do it by its own?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `ValidateIssuerSigningKey/IssuerSigningKey` since you are setting Authority/MetadataAddress , the middleware will take responsible for retrieving, caching, and refreshing the configuration from metadata , including the keys which publish by trust STS .

In OIDC authentication flows , if you getting the ID token from authorize endpoing in Hybrid or Implicit flow , middleware will help validate the signature and payload . But as document : https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation

> If  the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint, the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature.

And  see [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0a0e1ea0cdbe29f2fcd2291b900db98597387d77/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L671) of OIDC middleware , it will skip signature validation if ID token is received from token endpoint .

Comment: I am using the code flow. Do I have to implement validation on my own?

Comment: No , you don't need to .