# What is the meaning of ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience in JWT?

Tags: .net, jwt

I am developing an web api with jwt based authorization. The login endpoint returns the jwt token when credentials are correct.

I have configured the following values:

```
ValidateIssuer = false, 
ValidateAudience = false,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
```

I want to understand how they work.

1. ValidateIssuer:
   Is this property value automatically set or needs to be programmatically set?
   How does the validation work? How does the code know what is the current server to be able to validate?
2. ValidateAudience:
   By audience I believe it means the users of the application. Since my users can be from client (browser, mobile app) then how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for both flags is true, see the source code [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs)

What they do is

- **ValidateIssuer**, validates that the **iss** claim inside the access token matches the issuer(authority) that the API trusts (i.e., your token service). Verifies that the issuer of the token is what this API expects.
- **ValidateAudience**, validates that the **aud** claim inside the access token matches the audience parameter. Meaning, that the token received is meant for this API.

So, I recommend that you keep them true:

```
        .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.Authority = _configuration["openid:authority"];
            opt.Audience = "paymentapi";
```

Comment: Regarding `ValidateIssuer` - do you mean it will check the iss value that we set when making the token with the iss value in the jwt? I have the following property `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` set to true, in this case is there any use of setting `ValidateIssuer` or `ValidateAudience` to true?

Comment: You don't typically need to deal with ValidateIssuerSigningKey, because if you provide the authority, then the handler will download and manage the keys for you , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271251/asp-net-core-addopenidconnect-does-validateissuersigningkey-need-to-have-a-is

Comment: I am unable to understand what you mean by `because if you provide the authority, then the handler will download and manage the keys for you`. It will be very helpful if you could elaborate. My understanding is that - `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` confirms whether the jwt is really signed by the issuer (since only the issue will have the key).

Comment: Add the first incoming request, the AddJwtBearer handler will download the discovery document and the public signing keys from the JWKS endpoint. These keys are then used to validate the signature of the token. I have never had the need to change the default vaulue of ValidateIssuerSigningKey.

Comment: Validating the signature is of course the primary security defense, but then you also want to validate who sent it? perhaps there are multiple token providers in your org using the same key. Also you want to know that the token was meant for you (aud) and not some other service in your data center.

Comment: Are you saying that enabling ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience cover the check of whether the token is signed by the key? Then why is there ValidateIssuerSigningKey as separate option?

Comment: I think ValidateIssuerSigningKey is for more advanced use-cases that is not typically used for OpenIDConnect and JWT tokens. Perhaps when you manually provide the signing keys.

Comment: Last question - what do you mean by `when you manually provide the signing keys`?

Comment: In case you can't reach the token issuer directly to download the keys, perhaps due to firewall or other seucurity restrictions, then it can be useful to provide the public signing key manually.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? Why will the api send public signing key to user?

Comment: I mean not to the user. I mean in case the API receiving API tokens can't talk to the token issuer to get the keys. So they provide a way to provide the API with the necessary signing token to verify the signature.

Comment: I haven't understood your comment honestly.

Comment: You asked "Last question - what do you mean by when you manually provide the signing keys?", so I guess there is some rare cases where you would want to provide the signing key manual to your API instead of letting AddJwtBearer do it all for you.